# Firmar pdf con pfx mediante java en vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, pdf

Tengo un código para firmar un pdf con un certificado pfx mediante java, que funciona perfectamente en un proyecto web, pero no funciona en windowsforms, porque devuelve vacío en ReadToEnd.
Aquí os pongo el código.

```
Private Sub Ejecutar_firma(ByVal strexe As String, ByVal strargumentos As String, byval docfirmado As String)
   Dim certPfx As String = "Ruta_certificado_pfx"
   Dim cont As String = "contraseña_certificado"
   Dim rutaJar As String = "C:\SignPDF.jar"
   Dim temp As String = "-jar " & rutaJar & " --certfile=" & certPfx & " --password=" & cont & " --output=" & docfirmado    
Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(strexe, strargumentos)
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = False
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        Try
            Dim p As Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo)
            Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
            Dim cadenaSalida As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()

            If cadenaSalida = "" Then
                Label1.Text = "ERROR AL FIRMAR"
            Else
                Label1.Text = cadenaSalida
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = (ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

¿Sabría alguien decirme por qué no funciona?

Comment: ¿Devuelve algún error o entra directamente a `cadenaSalida = ""`?

Comment: CadenaSalida=""
y no devuelve error